# Collision of two diffrent object on GDI

Tags: c#

I want to create a simple game .
think I have two uneven ( not systematical ) GDI object in one Graphics , user move object one , and I want to be notified when object one has Collision with object two , how can I do this with C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw both the objects black on a single bitmap. Then draw one of them on a separate bitmap. Then subtract one bitmap from the other. If the result is same as the bitmap with the other object drawn on a separate bitmap then you have no collision otherwise you have a collision.

This doesn't require any math and works with objects of irregular shape. Just bitmap difference and sum operation.

Sudo code

```
var bmpObject1 = new bitmap->draw object 1
var bmpObject2 = new bitmap>draw object 2
var bmpCombined = new bitmap>draw object 1 and 2
if (bmpObject1 = (bmpCombined - bmpObject2))
    no collision
else
    collision
```